# xCode 4.3.2 - Understanding Add to Target

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite, sdk, target

I have an app which contains an SQLite database. I have just upgraded to Lion and xCode 4.3.2 and when I now drag and drop a new version of the database in xCode I get a box which asks if I want to "add the file to targets".

The box is not ticked by default. Is this correct or should I be adding an SQLite database to targets (and what does this mean) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A target specifies a product to build and contains the instructions for building the product from a set of files in a project or workspace - ([Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html))

Since you project may contain more than one targets (products) what XCode asks you basically is whether you want to include this asset in the target (so to have access to it).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should add the SQLite file to the target for which you want to use it. It means that you want to attach the file to specified target, In case of many targets you might want to add particular file to specific target.